# Networked Epson WF-2760 Scanner not detected in 64-bit 16.04.2

Tags: networking, drivers, scanner, epson

I am trying to get an Epson WF-2760 scanner that is network-connected working. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.2 64-bit and the printer works a treat. I have installed the Epson drivers from their site, including the plugins. I have edited /etc/sane.d/dll.conf to enable epson, epson2, and epsonds. I have edited each of the respective .conf files to include the network address of the device (IPV4: 192.168.128.11).

The scanner is not detected in any software that I have tried (including Image Scan and Simple Scan).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you install the proprietary drivers? How did you add the IP address?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did install the proprietary drivers. I added the IP address through the web-based administration console of the device. HTH!

Comment: What did you add and to which file in Ubuntu?

Comment: After installing the proprietary drivers and plugins with the install.sh script, I edited /etc/sane.d/dll.conf to uncomment epson, epson2, and add epkowa. I also edited /etc/sane.d/epson, epson2, and epkowa to include the network address, 192.168.128.11, which was static'd-in to the device. Lastly, I edited /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf to update the IP address for the scanner (it originally had a DHCP address, which the conf file captured). At this time, all IPs point to the .11.

Comment: Did you add the address to `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` as `net 192.168.128.11`? It is the only needed to be done.

Comment: Great question. Yes. I've tried it both with the IP address specified and set to autodiscovery. Currently, autodiscovery line is commented-out and the IP address line (net 192.168.128.11) is live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, color me embarrassed. The problem I had was that I didn't p-roofread enough. I had the epson2.conf setup with net 192.168.*1*.11, instead of 192.168.*128*.11. I looked at it so many times, I just didn't see it, I guess.

So here's the whole monte for getting the Epson WF 2760 working as a network-attached device.

Install the drivers at http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php?version=1.3.18 by running the install.sh script as root. Edit the file /etc/sane.d/dll.conf to uncomment the line "epson2". Edit the file /etc/sane.d/epson2.conf to include the line

```
net <your device's IP address>
```

Start your scanning program.

Thank you to the community for all the help!

Comment: I'm about to buy one of those. Can you confirm that this printer/scanner/fax works well with Ubuntu 16.04 and it is possible to use it with SANE? Your input would be really appreciated. Actually I guess it from your answer, but maybe that's only my wishful thinking ;)

Comment: Works great! Feel free to reach-out of you have any trouble.

Comment: I can use it now, but have two weird problems:
1) when I us Xsane to scan from ADF the printer "crashes"
2) when I use epson's imagescan program the output file disappears - it is visible and has the correct permissions during the scan but gets deleted(?) after the scan

Comment: Can you use the ADF with XSane? @eckster

Answer (score 2):

So, it looks like you have done some reading: I wonder which resources you used, as this seems a new device, and the Epson advice reads differently to previous texts. I would say that when you say "I have edited /etc/sane.d/dll.conf to enable epson, epson2, and epsonds" ..... I just wonder if that is what you need. It certainly is not in their [v3 manual](http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/imagescanv3_e.html#sec7);

Epson used to allow one to download a pdf manual, now, when I click on manual I get an online resource. I looked in that for advice on editing linux files, but they don't mention that. I wonder if the install script does that: tell us, did you use their install script?

Epspn say "Connect the scanner to the network and set the IP address.
For information on how to set the IP address, refer to the user manual shipped with your scanner." ... so I see you quote "network address of the device (IPV4: 192.168.128.11). "  ..... is that a static IP address you have set? .. I say that as my advice setting a static IP address for the device is the best way to go.  We have an older xp epson MFD and we did that from the front panel.

Your device has what they call the V3 version of imagescan and the advice is quite different now, and I agree: it is not straightforward; if you click on the next link, there is a screenshot of Epson's advice.  Sadly, USB for scanners is still so much easier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have not yet looked in the v3 manual that you reference. I will do so immediately, however, to see if there are any clues. The resources I used included several threads here and elsewhere on the web. Many people seem to have got other WorkForce all-in-ones working for them. // I did use the install script and I also tried to install the files manually, to no avail. The IP address is static'd in on the scanner, yes.

Comment: I had, in fact looked at that reference. My /etc/iimagescan/imagescan.conf file is as directed but no joy.

Comment: That made my Epson WorkForce WF-7710 work across WiFi. It even made [Simple Scan](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan) work. Somehow _Simple Scan_, probably via SANE, uses the non-free network-scanning plugin shipped with [Image Scan v3](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php) as configured in `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf`. Using a hostname (instead of an IP address) is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

if I paste this link: the wiki on networked scanning; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#Permission_Issues 
You seem pretty capable at doing all these things; so if you check through it; (you may already have done it!)

Comment: I really appreciate the input! Sadly, the direct-connect section does not address Epson devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify pdc's answer, which worked for me to be able to use the Epson ET-2712 scanner in Ubuntu 18.04 trough Wifi:

The content of /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf (which you can edit using the following command `gedit /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf` with sudo powers) should be:

```
[devices]
net.udi=networkscan:esci://192.168.1.12:1865 # ADAPT WITH YOUR PRINTER'S IP, leave the :1865 PORT
net.vendor=Epson
net.model=ET-2712
net.name=ARBITRARYNAME
```