# What can I do to make my Epson Workforce 2760 scanner function in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: scanner

Since upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 my Epson Workforce 2760 printer will not scan documents. I have tried everything I can find related to this problem with zero success. I have tried installing backends and setting permissions. There are others who are having this problem but perhaps not enough to get to a level that attracts the attention of someone who can help. There may be a bug in the 18.04 version that causes this and hopefully either a workaround or a fix can be discovered soon.

One thing I tried was this:

```
sudo ln -sfr /usr/lib/sane/libsane-epkowa* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
```

Still no success. Possibly the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 broke something within the Sane setup. I don't know how to "provide some more details, like the output for lsusb to prove the scanner is actually attached and recognized." 
Found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012

Here is output of "sudo sane-find-scanner" :
 # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

# No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x111c [EPSON WF-2760 Series]) at libusb:005:002
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

# Not checking for parallel port scanners.

# Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tied so far in relation to software solutions.

Comment: You need to provide some more detials, like the output for lsusb to prove the scanner is actually attached and recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to the SANE project "[supported devices](http://sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-EPSON)" list, your scanner isn't supported.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make my printer/scanner functional in Ubuntu 18.04. It worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @lab7755 I think that 16.04 was able to detect and use that scanner because some "trick" has been applied. I would also try to reinstall some SANE libraries. Try `sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install libsane libsane-extras` and then again `sudo sane-find-scanner` and `sudo scanimage -L`.  Use `sudo` first to avoid possible issues with device permissions, then without it.

Comment: I appreciate your help but still I cannot use my scanner.

Comment: The list of supported devices is not complete. I got my WF-7710 working across WiFi. My guess is, all Epson WorkForce models work through the non-free network-scanning driver-plugin supplied with Epson's [Image Scan v3](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php) software. Some additional, manual setup is necessary. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/895002: You have to set the hostname or IP address in `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf`. (The autodiscovery, as in `/etc/sane.d/epson2.conf`, is not doing it for the driver-plugin.)