# Epson Scan is not working in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, scanner, epson

I am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS . I have a EPSON L220 All-in-One printer ( printer + scanner). I successfully configure the printer setting and printing is done very well. But scanner is not working. 
I have downloaded the epson scanner driver from http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php, extract the zip file, open a terminal, go to the folder and and run the command `./install.sh` from terminal, it simply run the command without any error. But when I open software Image Scan!for linux , then it shows the following error message [image]

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/895002, it answers your question. You have to set the hostname or IP address in `/etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf`. (The autodiscovery, as in `/etc/sane.d/epson2.conf`, is somewhat not working with the supplied non-free network-scanning driver-plugin.)

Comment: @Peterino My printer is not network printer , my printer is USB ink-jet all-in-one printer .

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, this was broken at some point, and fixed in 19.04, but never
backported to 18.04 LTS (which it should have been!)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sane-backends/+bug/1728012

There should be some way to notify the 18.04 LTS team that this fix
should be backported, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Jut to compile in a single answer something that worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 for an Epson ET-2712:

1. Download and install: http://support.epson.net/linux/en/imagescanv3.php
2. `gedit /etc/imagescan/imagescan.conf` [as sudo]: see **Content of imagescan.conf** below
3. Enjoy!

### Content of imagescan.conf:

```
[devices]

net.udi=networkscan:esci:networkscan://192.168.[COMPLETE WITH YOUR PRINTER IP]:1865
net.vendor = Epson
net.model  = ET-2712
net.name  = WHATEVERNAMEYOULIKE
```

Answer (score 1):

￼I had the same problem, lsusb found the scanner, the scanner is detected by `sane-find-scanner -L`.

Adding the following line to `/etc/rc.local` : `chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb`

fixed the problem, clearly an access issue. After this it all works. However, this is not a safe solution for a system accessible from the net.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to
   [epson.net](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)
   and search L220 (below select linux)
2. click on appropriate <kbd>download</kbd> button for scanner "ESC"
3. then <kbd>Accept</kbd>, then <kbd>Package download page</kbd>; then <kbd>Download</kbd> according to distrib.
4. After downloading `tar.gz`, untar, in terminal with:

   ```
    tar xzvf file.tar.gz
   ```
5. Then enter folder `cd filenamefolder` in terminal, and then `./install.sh`